# How to suppress missing_docs warnings for substrate macros?

Tags: pallet, documentation

I tried using the `#![warn(missing_docs)]` macro to check for missing documentation in my pallet, but when running clippy it complains about some pallet macros

```
warning: missing documentation for a struct
   --> frame/clearing-house/src/lib.rs:128:12
    |
128 |       #[pallet::storage]
    |  _______________^
129 | |     /// Supported collateral asset ids
130 | |     pub type CollateralTypes<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, AssetIdOf<T>, ()>;
    | |_______^
```

even though I documented the type declaration. Is there a fix for this? Or is it not worth using the `#![warn(missing_docs)]` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this was a result of a bug in the pallet macro. It was generating functions that are internal usage and didn't hide them for the docs. This should now be fixed after https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11075 this is merged.